# How do I check if current code is "inside" lock?

Tags: c#, locking

I have some code that can be called from inside **or** outside a lock. I need to do stuff when inside the lock. The code itself has no knowledge of where it's being called from. So, I need something like this:

```
lock (MyLock) {
    if (INSIDE_LOCK) ...
}
```

I know it sounds weird and wrong but I need this for compatibility issues. Otherwise I will have to rewrite a lot of code, which would be risky since I have no tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Monitor` class:

```
 if (Monitor.IsEntered(MyLock)) {...}
```

Since (see René Vogt comment below) `lock`

```
 lock(MyLock) {
   ...
 }
```

is, in fact a syntactic sugar for

```
 Monitor.Enter(MyLock);

 try {
   ... 
 }  
 finally {
   Monitor.Leave(MyLock);
 }
```

Comment: some explanation about `lock(MyLock)` being just syntactic sugar for `Monitor.Enter(MyLock)` + `try/finally` + `Monitor.Leave(MyLock)` could improve this one-line-answer.